# Unable to connect carrier wave to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am trying to push an app to heroku so I need to convert my carrierwave setup to store images to an s3 bucket. I followed the guide on the [carrierwave readme](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3) but no matter what I do I can't seem to get the images to save to my bucket.

First I added the fog gem.

```
#carrierwave gemfile
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mini_magick"
gem "fog"
```

Then created a amazon s3 account and made an IAM user with an administrator policy and generated an access key and secret for that user. I then created a bucket and set the grantee to everyone.

Back in my app I changed the storage to fog in the image_uploader and created an initializer with the following values:

```
#config/initializers/fog.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => 'myaccesskeyid',
      :aws_secret_access_key  => 'mysecretaccesskey',
      :region                 => 'US Standard'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'my-bucket'
end
```

After restarting the server and trying to upload an image I get a broken image with a link like `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/image/url/56/inline_content_MOWEFbYOJKSLVM0LeTslBn1l7URjrwAn7w6qLd-kbbU.jpeg` but the bucket remains empty and the image has not been uploaded. I have tried creating different buckets, using my old root key for the aws account but nothing seems to work. I am in Europe using the US region but that shouldn't make a difference. I can't seem to find any errors that would explain what is going wrong but where would I look besides my server log?

EDIT:
I tried setting up a google storage bucket and changed the credentials but it still gives a broken image and nothing is uploaded to the bucket.

Comment: The initializer is wrong you need to change accesskeys and region and also your my-bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I downgraded my fog version to 1.24.0 and it started working!

`gem "fog", '1.24.0'`